# Stripe API - How To Get When A Payment Method Is Added To A Customer's Account?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently using the *allSources()* (https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list) method to get a list of credit cards associated with a user.  This method does not return the date for which each individual card was added to the user's account.

Is there a way to get this info from Stripe?  The idea being I want to display payment cards to a user in the order which the user added them to their account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Card` object does not have a `created` property today. What you could do here is rely on the order in the `sources` sub-collection as it's always ordered by most recent first. The exception is that the current default source (the one set in `default_source`) is always the first in the collection even if it's not the most recently created.

Alternatively, what you could do is move to the `PaymentMethod` APIs instead. This is the most recent abstraction from Stripe which replaces `Card` and `Source` entirely. This object does have a `created` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-created). You can use the List PaymentMethod [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list) to list them for a specific customer.

When Stripe built that new API they made it compatible with existing, and now considered legacy, objects. What this means is that you can have a Card object with the id `card_123` and that will also work via the PaymentMethod API moving forward. The id stays the same and you don't need to do anything. If you list the PaymentMethods on your customer you will "magically" get the old card objects as PaymentMethod objects which means they will have a `created` property.